# Second Contextual Filter on Calendar Module

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm attempting to add a second contextual filter to a Calendar view generated by the Calendar module.

I'm using the entity reference module to reference all my 'Events' to 'Clients'. My desired outcome is to go to a url like `example.com/client/[client-nid]/calendar/month` and for the calendar to only display events that reference that client.

My Event content type has an entity reference field 'Client'. In my view, I have added a Contextual Filter for this field and set it to validate against 'Content', specifying 'Client' as the content type and Filter Value Format is Node Id.

When i use this view though `example.com/client/182/calendar/month` I only see a calendar with a single event on it, even though there are many nodes that reference node 182. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Entity reference field can not provide content id to your view through contextual filter by default. You'll need to define a relationship to your entity reference field so that view is able to pick up Client node id ( content:nid) as contextual filter.

Remove contextual filter that you have now and add relationship to the entity reference field 'Client'. Then add contextual filter to Content:nid. In relationship setting select the alias of relationship that you added previously. In the section " When filter value is not available" check 'Provide default value -> raw value from url -> path component = 2'. Also check "use path alias".

Comment: Can you explain the relationship setting? I wasn't using a relationship setting to begin with.

Comment: I've tried this out, and i've found that when my url is structured like this: `clients/2016-01/calendar/month/182` I get the desired results, but when I do the opposite: `clients/182/calendar/month/2016-01` I get a month display that only shows content from the current day. Is there a way to specify the order?

Comment: you have to set up page url structure in your view settings and place "%" where you contextual filter will be. I.e. like this -> "`client/%/calendar/month`" - is that how you doing it?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i've got

Comment: for contextual filter, try -"When the filter value is not in the URL" -> Show "No Results found" and see if that fixes the issue